# Android app needs to access stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app

At my school, we have a web-blocker system that categorizes websites and the school has decided to block certain categories.<sup>1</sup> Stackexchange.com is categorized as forums and hence blocked, but stackoverflow.com is accessible. I use the stack exchange app on my android tablet as the default opener for all stack overflow links. However, when I click on a stackoverflow link and the stack exchange app tries to open it, it can't because it has to access stackexchange.com which is blocked. Why can't the app access only stackoverflow.com when trying to view a stackoverflow question?

<sub>Android 4.3 on Nexus 7 [2012] with App v. 0.1.39</sub>

<sup>1</sup><sub>I asked why we block forums, and was told that we don't block specific forums, we block the category forums, and if I find a forum that shouldn't be blocked, I should complain on the blocked page. I complained, but to no avail.</sub>

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the app utilizes the API, requiring a connection to SE before SO.

Comment: No. The API does not allow answering any asking questions. The app does.

Comment: The app uses currently-unreleased API methods, but it's still through the API.

Comment: Your school blocks StackExchange for forums, but not Stack Overflow? Well, they're correct with Stack Overflow; it's not a forum, but I fail to see Stack Exchange. You don't ask questions on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I find it unfortunate that an American school district needs to block all forums by default and enable them on a case-by-case basis.  There are so many *semi*-valuable forums that you are forcing students to use non-traditional methods to find data.

Comment: Oddly enough, my school blocks gaming.SE but doesn't block Chat...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it's the *Stack Exchange* app, not the Stack Overflow app.

But really, think about it. In order to do that, they'd need to enable API access from all sites. Then you'd need extra checks to only allow Stack Overflow data from the stackoverflow.com API, because it wouldn't make sense to access Gaming SE data from there... You'd also need extra code in the app itself to determine which domain to access the API from.

That all sounds like a *lot* of extra work just to avoid a network block. Because let's face it, there's not any other reason why this would need to be done.